# Mouse not working sometimes after login [Kubuntu 20.04]

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

Since I installed Kubuntu 20.04 sometimes my mouse does not work on startup and I have to replug it to make it work. I've tried sudo *apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all* but it does not make any difference. When this happens the exit of *xinput -list* does not show the mouse, otherwise it does.
The mouse is a Corsair Harpoon.

Comment: Do you have any other USB ports you could try the mouse in?  I was having issues with my mouse when I had it plugged into a USB 1.1 port instead of a USB 2 port.  Maybe check if USB Legacy mode is enabled or disabled in BIOS and try the opposite setting.

Comment: I have 4 x usb 3 and 2 x usb 2 (Asus Maximus VII Ranger), I have both mouse and keyboard connected in usb 2, tried to change them to usb 3 and the issue seems to occur more often than usb 2. I also tried disabling USB legacy (enabled by default) but that does not make any difference. Thanks for your answer.